# How can i display multi series column chart in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, data-visualization, mschart

In my web application, I need to display column chart data bind from data table i have 3 columns in that X-axis in my chart area i need to display col1 one side and column 2nd and i need to display different colors for series display legend also from data table.

i need same like this how can i do this please anyone can help me how to do this.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your `DataTable` has the following column/types:

```
    Columns.Add("Month", typeof(DateTime));
    Columns.Add("Charges", typeof(double));
    Columns.Add("Payments", typeof(double));
```

**ASPX:**

```
    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="600px">
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                <AxisY>
                    <MajorGrid LineColor="DarkGray" LineDashStyle="Dot" />
                    <LabelStyle Format="C2" />
                </AxisY>
                <AxisX>
                    <MajorGrid LineColor="DarkGray" LineDashStyle="Dot" />
                </AxisX>
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
        <Legends>
            <asp:Legend Name="Legend1">
            </asp:Legend>
        </Legends>
    </asp:Chart>
```

**CS:**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            Series s = new Series(string.Format("{0} {1}", ((DateTime)r["Month"]).ToString("MMM"), ((DateTime)r["Month"]).Year));
            s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
            s.Points.AddXY("Charges", new object[] { r["Charges"] });
            s.Points.AddXY("Payments", new object[] { r["Payments"] });

            Chart1.Series.Add(s);
        }
    }
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:** Assuming your `DataTable` has the following column / types:

```
    Columns.Add("Month", typeof(string));
    Columns.Add("Charges", typeof(double));
    Columns.Add("Payments", typeof(double));
```

OR

```
    Columns.Add("Month");
    Columns.Add("Charges");
    Columns.Add("Payments");
```

Then you should change the the code to this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            Series s = new Series((string)r["Month"]);
            s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
            s.Points.AddXY("Charges", new object[] { r["Charges"] });
            s.Points.AddXY("Payments", new object[] { r["Payments"] });

            Chart1.Series.Add(s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What column types you have in your table?

Comment: In my data table i have already `Month` column and values like this `Aug-2016` how can i take that into series

Comment: What are the types for each column in your table? What is the type for `Month` column? What is the type for `Payments` column ? What is the type for `Charges` column ?

Comment: when i take columns for `Month` values `08/01/2016 00:00:00` after i changed it will come like this `Aug-2016`, Column `Charge` values `205711.7900` it will changed to `Rupee values` and `Payments` values also same like that. could please tell me how to do this i searched a lot for this i am not getting

Comment: I edited my answer, please see if that works for you.

Comment: Hi jstreet, i updated my data table image can you please see that once and tell me where i did mistake

Comment: Please try the code i suggested in my **EDIT** and let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much Jstreet Thanks a lot. thank you.Your awesome It's working You helped me a lot